# Count non empty rows mysql

Tags: php, mysql, count, rows

How to count non empty rows from 'naziv_operacije'? You can see table on the picture

[image]

Comment: Define empty? are the empty values null of empty strings like ''

Comment: Table is called TEHN, and column is naziv_operacije. I want to count how many rows are that are filled.

Comment: Instead of posting an image, post the table structure ([`SHOW CREATE TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-create-table.html)) and specify what do you mean by "empty". It can be an empty string, it can be `NULL`, it can be something else (the string `"      "`, f.e.). All these are "empty" but they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the rows are empty strings or null, the below should do it:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `TEHN`
WHERE `naziv_operacije` IS NOT NULL OR `naziv_operacije` != '';
```

Comment: 1. the column is numeric... 2. _IS NOT NULL **OR**_ should be changed to _IS NOT NULL **AND**_

Comment: @bub It is not defined anywhere that the column is numeric. Also please explain the reasoning behind AND, it actually should be OR, it can never be both NULL and an empty string. It's one or the other.

Comment: well it is... look at the attached picture which shows the table structure ;)

Comment: It shows numbers but that doesn't mean that it isn't a varchar/char column

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select count(column_name) from naziv_operacije;
```

Replace *column_name* with the column which should not be empty

Comment: @bub to ensure the field is not empty I have read the [documentation of `COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) and I'm sure Jonathan did the same. Have you read it?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [`COUNT()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count) explains:

> `COUNT(expr)`
>
> `Returns a count of the number of non-`NULL`values of`expr`in the rows retrieved by a`SELECT`statement. The result is a`BIGINT` value.
>
> `COUNT(*)` is somewhat different in that it returns a count of the number of rows retrieved, whether or not they contain `NULL` values.

**If** by "empty" you mean `NULL` then `COUNT(naziv_operacije)` is all you need.
Run this query to see how it works:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(naziv_operacije) AS not_empty,
    COUNT(*) AS all
FROM TEHN
```